# Cannot read property of undefined reading existing array in json

Tags: angular, typescript

Why do I keep getting **undefined** error messages and how to avoid them when I try reading json data?

I am learning Angular and working on a project using externally sourced json. A sampling of the json is below. The primary data I need is in the **included** array:

```
{jsonapi: {…}, data: {…}, included: Array(2), links: {…}}
jsonapi: {version: "1.0", meta: {…}}
data: {type: "node--quiz", id: "31f020f7-34d9-4b9a-bd2b-0d567eb285dc", attributes: {…}, links: {…}}
included: Array(2)
    0: {type: "node--question", id: "afe7137a-2af1-4cb5-92da-879c495c0070", attributes: {…}, links: {…}}
    1:
    type: "node--question"
    id: "79c06ac9-5995-409f-b84c-4d8a9711d0a9"
    attributes: {title: "Question 1", body: {…}, field_options: "{
    ↵   "1":{
    ↵      "type":"select",
    ↵      "option…   ],
    ↵      "answer":"methamphetamines"
    ↵   }
    ↵}", field_processed: "s:390:"<p>The genius chemist {"type":"select","opt…etamines"} in the Breaking Bad tv series.</p>
    ↵";"}
links: {self: {…}}
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
links: {self: {…}}
__proto__: Object
```

My **app.component.html** is as follows:

```
<mat-toolbar  color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
  <span>{{ title }}</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <main>
    <mat-card *ngFor="let question of questions.included">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title> {{ question.attributes.title }} </mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
          {{ question.attributes.body.value }}
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        TESTING: body content
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </main>
```

But I get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'included' of undefined` in my browser console from the point where *ngFor is executing.

Comment: This one [should also give you some background](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) on using language effectively here.

Comment: It seems that some of our conversation has been removed by mods, which is fair enough. One of my comments was left undeleted though, so I will add an addendum to supply some useful context. Your questions have consistently contained pleading material that may have resulted in readers downvoting or skipping over your posts. This has been going on for years. If you want a better reception here - as well as helping editors maintain the technical writing requirements on the site - then please read the above link.

Comment: @halfer: What you call pleading, I call being polite

Comment: I understand that. The point of my edits is to indicate that the community does not agree with your view, and it is exactly the opposite of polite to carry on doing it.

Comment: [This answer also adds some context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391903/what-to-do-when-a-user-targets-your-question-history/391945#391945) about politeness and how it is perceived by readers, and in particular why readers may find it tiresome to read through reams of helplessness. This topic also encompasses a philosophical dilemma: language means what the reader thinks it means, and not what the writer meant. Writers unavoidably have to deal with that if they want to be understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the data exists, it needs to be there when the form is loaded. You can handle this with a simple safe navigation operator as follows,

```
 <mat-card *ngFor="let question of questions?.included">
```